# How to render/navigate a component on condition basis

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have index.android.js where I am getting value of key from `AsyncStorage` if value is true then I want to navigate to `DashboardScreen` and else `StackNav`.

index.android.js

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { StackNav } from "./router";
export default class ScheduledApp extends Component {
  render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("@ProductTour:key").then(value => {
        // control goes inside if when user has completed product tour
        if (value) {
          navigate("DashboardScreen");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    return <StackNav />;
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Scheduled", () => ScheduledApp);
```

router.js

```
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import SplashScreen from "./ui/SplashScreen";
import EnableNotificationScreen from "./ui/EnableNotificationScreen";
import CreateMessageScreen from "./ui/CreateMessageScreen";
import DashboardScreen from "./ui/DashboardScreen";
import CreateSMS from "./ui/CreateSMS";

export const StackNav = StackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
      screen: SplashScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    EnableNotification: {
      screen: EnableNotificationScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    CreateMessage: {
      screen: CreateMessageScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    },
    DashboardScreen: {
      screen: DashboardScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerLeft: null,
        headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: "center" }
      }
    },
    CreateSMS: {
      screen: CreateSMS
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Splash"
  }
);
```

Does anyone know how to render/navigate component on condition basis ?

Comment: Your error doesn't seem to match your code. In the error your destructured assignment is outside of the render function, in which case is an invalid syntax. But your code seem to have it inside the render function.

Comment: I agree with @CarlosC and the `this.props.navigation` is not exposed yet in your `ScheduledApp` component.

Comment: @CarlosC correct, no errors now. but do you know how to render if value is true then I want to navigate to `DashboardScreen` and else `StackNav.`?

Comment: I tried this also https://pastebin.com/BLefZn4H but didn't work for me

Comment: Just return null as in the snippet below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default class ScheduledApp extends Component {
  render() {            
    return <StackNav />;
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("Scheduled", () => ScheduledApp);
```

And then in your SplashScreen component:

```
export default class ScheduledApp extends Component {
  render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("@ProductTour:key").then(value => {
        // control goes inside if when user has completed product tour
        if (value) {
          navigate("DashboardScreen");
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    return <Text>Return whatever you are already returning in the SplashScreen render function</Text>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am gettting "cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined". It looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790132/how-to-render-navigate-a-component-on-condition-basis?noredirect=1#comment78539277_45790132 do you know how to do that ?

Comment: I edited my response, so think of the StackNav component as a wrapper component and that all the screens navigate inside of it and have the "navigate" prop. ScheduledApp was not "wrapped" by the StackNav, so it didn't have "navigate" as a prop.